# how to use ui-view in modal dialg box Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to change data from popup Modal dialog box.. i have given `<modal><div ui-view=""></div></modal>` tag in modal directive.. but ui router in not working on that dialog popup modal ... how to use ui view router with in a directive ...

```js
app.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div class="modal fade">' +
                '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
                '<div class="modal-content">' +
                '<div class="modal-header">' +
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.title = attrs.title;

            scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function (value) {
                if (value == true)
                    $(element).modal('show');
                else
                    $(element).modal('hide');
            });

            $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
                });
            });

            $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: you have `replace: true`. This will replace the `<modal>`-element and everything inside with what ever you have in the directives template. Secondly angular-ui have a library for using modals which you should probably check out, [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: @Gustav thats good, there is also i am facing issue.. can u pls tell me the exact solution to my above problem

Comment: You should search a bit on google, there is very good examples http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-stateful-modals-angularjs-angular-ui-router/